# WooCommerce update product in php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I need to update the name of my WooCommerce product. I am trying via a small plugin. The method I use, DOES update the first product in the loop, but also immediately throws a "critical error", the echo after the WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT::update( $product ) does not ever get executed:

```
foreach($products as $product){

            if ($product instanceof WC_Product) {
                echo 'Ye its a product';

            $new_name='new name';
            $product->set_name($new_name);

            WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT::update( $product );
            echo "<br>--------------------<br>";
        }}
```

Comment: You should replace `WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT::update( $product );` by `$product->save();`… It should work…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ( $products as $product ) {

    if ( $product instanceof WC_Product ) {

        $new_name = 'new name';
        wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $product->get_id(), 'post_title' => $new_name ) );
        echo "<br>--------------------<br>";
    }
}
```

Try this.

Comment: it does update the title, i see that in the UI, but then when i get the name with $product->get_name(); it does not actually contain the new name. If its a product, should we not work with the products properties instead of the post_title?

Comment: After running the code, please check by clearing transients and transient cache under WooCommerce->Settings->Status ( This approach is a little bit faster )